# How do you create multiple objects from a class in Python using an equivalent algorithm to this one in Java?

Tags: java, python

I've written a piece of code in Java to create multiple objects for a problem solving exercise. This worked successfully, but I'm now trying to write it in Python and can't work out how to do it. 
I want to have a list of objects, each with unique values, that I can use in the rest of my code.

Here's my Java code:

```
public void createSquares() {
        int square = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int r=1; r<10; r++) {
            for (int c=1; c<10; c++) {
                if (r<4 && c<4) {
                    square = 1;
                }
                else if (r<4 && c>3 && c<7){
                    square = 2;
                }
                else if (r<4 && c>6){
                    square = 3;
                }
                else if (r>3 && r<7 && c<4){
                    square = 4;
                }
                else if (r>3 && r<7 && c>3 && c<7){
                    square = 5;
                }
                else if (r>3 && r<7 && c>6){
                    square = 6;
                }
                else if (r>6 && c<4){
                    square = 7;
                }
                else if (r>6 && c>3 && c<7){
                    square = 8;
                }
                else if (r>6 && c>6){
                    square = 9;
                }
                Square s = new Square(r, c, square, count);  //How does this work in Python?
                sList.add(count, s);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you having trouble calling the constructor? It's the same thing, but without the `new`. To make the class itself define a function called `__init__` that takes `self` and 4 other parameters

Answer (score 2):

In python, constructors (in a method called `__init__`) accept a parameter called `self` representing the object itself, before any other parameter.

```py
class Square:
    def __init__(self, r, c, square, count): # Create the constructor, accepting 4 parameters
        self.r = r
        self.c = c
        self.square = square
        self.count = count
```

And in your main loop:

```py
s = Square(r, c, square, count) # Notice there is no "self" here, and the keyword "new" is not used
list.append(s) # Python lists use "append" and not "add"
count += 1
```